# Concurrency on vector where each cell is 8 bit on a 32 bit architecture

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, architecture

Let's suppose to have a concurrency situation with a *vector*. 
Each thread accesses to different cells of the array, in *write* and read mode.

I'm going to present a "*C/C++-like*" snippet of code, just to give an idea:

```
uint8_t vector[SIZE];

void thread(int id_thread) {
  // vector is a global variable, same for all threads
  vector[id_thread] = id_thread;
}

// Somewhere
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
  createThread(thread, i);  // create a thread and passing i as id_thread
}
```

## The idea

- A vector composed by *num-*`SIZE` cells.
- *Each cell has a size of a `uint8_t`* (8 bit, 1 byte).
- Each thread writes and reads in *different* cells, in other words: don't exist two different threads overlapping on the vector.

## Question

Suppose to have a moder, common PC architecture: *intel(R)* processor 64 bit.
Do I have any guarantee about the safety (in term of concurrency) of those operations?

The question becomes from the fact the processor accesses to the memory bringing inside its registers a *WORD* (32-bit or 64-bit), when a cell is of 8 bit.

Could it happen that two thread write two adjacent vector cells and produce a *ghost write*? Or is there an obscure (for me) "design" which avoids that?

```
[0] [0] [0] [0] ... [0]
_______________   
  uint8 * 4

thread1:   [1] [0] [0] [0]  and write in memory 
thread2:   [0] [1] [0] [0]  and write in memory
           ---------------
           overlap if processor write 32-bit at least.
```

Am I wrong? The processor can write a single byte in the memory without touch in any way (*caches*, including) adjacent bytes?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply make sure that you split the work between threads based on system alignment. Each thread should have `n * alignment` bytes of data to work with.

Comment: I believe there is some mechanism which like Scott Meyers said "marks it dirty" and forbids two threads to use the same cacheline at the same time when they intend to write to it (does not happen when they only read it).

Comment: BTW "32-bit architecture" doesn't really specify whether a CPU is able to address and read/write single bytes of memory atomically or not. That is another property of the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is free to implement the writes as machine instructions however it wants so long as it can't break single-threaded code. It could, for example, read a 32-bit value into a register, change the appropriate byte, and write the 32-bit value back to memory. This would clobber other writes.